# MongoDB Shard Cluster routing

Tags: mongodb

I want to learn the entire route of a MongoDB query to the MongoDB Sharded Cluster, and back with the result. Does it pass from the mongos to a config server and then to one of the shards, then it returns to the config and back to the client driver or otherwise?

Thank you!

Comment: I a pretty sure this is in the documentation under sharding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query is sent from your application to a local or remote `mongos` instance which, contrary to its name (Mongo Shard), is in fact a router.

If your query contains the shard key then the `mongos` router will use cached data from the config servers to determine what shards to query.

If your query does not contain the shard key then MongoDB will do a scatter and gather operation, basically asking all shards for their results to a certain query.

In both cases the `mongos` will parallelize the queries to multiple shards and then return the final result.

Everytime you run a `getMore()` on your cursor to get another batch of results it must redo the query, even if it is a scatter and gather operation.

Answer (score 3):

A query goes from client to mongos to the right data node in a shard's replicaset. The config server is only consulted by mongos to know on which shard the data lives and this config data is generally cached by mongos. Your query and results do not pass through a config server, only through mongos, and of course the data node that runs the query and returns the results.

Comment: Can you be more specific as in "detailed"? Thank you!

Comment: There isn't much more to say here - what are you expecting?